# Error with command gdb. Debugging problem in eclipse

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt, lldb

I am a beginner and im trying to understand and use eclipse on my new MacBook. Eclipse has been working fine for few days, but today suddenly I can run, build but not debug the code, it shows

> Error with command: gdb --version Cannot run program "gdb": Unknown
>   reason

So I spent time googling and found a solution, and that was to install another debugger (LLDB). I did so but the problem remains

This is what I get:

> Error with command: lldb-mi --version Cannot run program "lldb-mi":
>   Unknown reason

The code is super normal, here it is for instance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I also found advices like looking for MinGW and gdb.exe but i couldnt find MinGW on my computer, does it mean I have to install one? And maybe these pictures will help you understand my situation better.
Please, help, thank you!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone with a similar problem: I needed to install a gdb of newer version 8.3 with Homebrew. You will need to codesign it manually but it shall be fine.

Wish you all best of luck!

Comment: And to lead those poor even better to your answer, please mark it. ;-)